# I need to know how to pronounce the name "Job" in Italian

Tags: pronunciation

So a long time ago, there was this Italian chemist (at least I think he was Italian, because he published in Italian journals of chemistry), whose last name was Job. He invented a really useful tool that chemists still use to this day called a Job plot (useful for predicting trends in reactivity of similar kinds of molecules). However, no one seems to know how to pronounce it: some say it so that it rhymes with "rob", and some say it so that it rhymes with "robe".

So, I did some digging, and found out he was probably Italian; I thought it might be best to ask some native Italian speakers how that name would be pronounced.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A Google search didn't show any famous Italian chemist. Anyway I have a friend of my with that surname. His surname is pronounced like 'rob' but the initial 'j' is pronounced like 'e'. Hope it is clear.

Comment: If you're talking about how Italians pronounce it, it would sound like "djobbah". (Yeah I know, I'm racist) :)

Comment: @writingthesis that would be the pronounciation of the english word job, but i think the j in the surname it's like the j in jacopo, so it would be pronounded as "iob" (in italian)

Answer (score 5):

I cannot find a source but I'd bet the pronunciation was /job/ (IPA: the first is a semivocalic sound, as in “yard”, not an English “j”), as in the [ancient Italian form of the name of the prophet Job](http://www.europeana.eu/portal/record/9200369/BibliographicResource_3000113671661.html) (in modern Italian, Giobbe).

There is at least another famous Italian named Job: [Enrico Job](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enrico_Job), art director and writer (and the husband of movie director Lina Wertmüller). In [this video](http://www.mediatecaroma.it/mediatecaRoma/canali/Arte_e_Spettacolo.html?show=14&index=0&jsonVal=&filter=&query=&id=BdR000000266) Wertmüller pronounces his name as described above (at 1:19 approx.).

Comment: That should be /jɔb/, right? At least, that's the way Lina Wertmüller pronounces Job at least 3 times in that video, and it's the Italian pronunciation for sure. But the name _could_ be of German origin, given it's [frequency in northern Italy](http://www.gens.info/italia/it/turismo-viaggi-e-tradizioni-italia?cognome=job&x=0&y=0). The German pronunciation would be /jo:p/.

Answer (score 4):

The author of the paper was [Paul Job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_plot). Though it was published in an Italian journal, Job was French - a student of [Georges Urbain](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/5456/1/hrst.mit.edu/hrs/materials/public/Caro/Caro_intro.htm) and cousin of [André Job](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Job)<sup>[1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zOXB_AVT08kC&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=%22paul+job%22+chemistry)</sup>, teaching at the Ecole nationale supérieure de chimie de Paris (ENSCP), and born in     [Nancy (Meurthe-et-Moselle)](http://data.bnf.fr/10792471/paul_job/).

Given all this, I think we can assume it was pronounced in an early 20th century French fashion, presumably `/ʒɔb/`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about P. Job? who wrote the paper about the [Job Plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_plot) in 1928 in the [Annali di chimica applicata](http://www.worldcat.org/title/annali-di-chimica-applicata/oclc/4414603)?

I think he was not originally from Italy, or at least his father was not, because native Italian words (and therefore last names) do not contain "j", "k", "w", "x", "y".

I would it pronounce just like I would pronounce "Job" in English.

p.s. I could not find any info about him, so if you at least know his first name please share!

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted?

Comment: Late to the party, but while uncommon native Italian words do contain "j" and "x" (unless you're going to tell me that *naja* and *xilofono* aren't native Italian words, see also the city of Jesolo)

Comment: *Xilofono* comes from German *Xylophon*, and has a nativised Italian doublet *silofono*. Proper names containing *x* are mainly from other Romance languages (e.g. *Craxi*, Sicilian). Those containing *j* (*Jesolo, Juventus, Jacopo, Ojetti, Ajaccio*) are remnants of an older spelling convention where semi-consonantal *i* (and plural suffix of *-io*) was spelled *j*, which fell out of use in almost all other words between the mid 19th and 20th centuries (eg *jeri/ieri; jonico/ionico; jella/iella; jena/iena; juta/iuta; jod/iod, yod; fidejussione/fideiussione; alleluja/alleluia; varj/varî, vari*).

Comment: @tjfuke Granted, they are nowadays uncommon letters, but *x* and *j* have no reason not to be part of the Italian alphabet,  (see for other examples, *xenofobo*, *xilografia*, *jacuzzi*). Most of them are reliquiae from older spelling conventions and borrowings but they do exist and are Italian words (and that spelling convention was still used by Pirandello, less than a century ago). See also [this webpage by the Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_657.html)